# an area of the earth that is to be partitioned into 100 km by 100 km square areas

Tags: google-maps, math, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Let's say I have a large geographic area SW (South-West) Latitude, Longitude and NE (North-East) Lat, Long and I want multiple areas of 100KM by 100KM squares to be divided.

So that if large part has 1000KM by 1000KM then I need ten of 100KM by 100KM squares area to be partitioned with their SW LAT-LONG and NE LAT-LONG.

Any sample formula that does the partition?

Comment: You will actually need one hundred 100KM by 100KM to cover 1000KM by 1000KM

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, since they're on tne surface of a sphere they will not be exact squares, but curved surfaces with parallel top and bottom boundaries and non-parallel side boundaries. and since the latitude of the northern-most row of "squares" will be different than the latitude of the southernmost row, you have to decide how important is it that the sides (vertical boundaries) be exactly 100 km...

(Side note: it is impossible -very very difficult -- to guarantee that the top and bottom horizontal boundaries will be exactly 100 km, unless the "square" exactly straddles the equator)

If it is critical, then the vertical boundaries between "squares in each row will not line up with the vertical boundary lines of the row above and below it... On the other hand if the length of the sides is not critical, i.e., if only the *area* of each "square" needs to be the same, then you can make the vertical lines (side boundaries) coincident between rows and just make each successive row of "squares a bit taller or short (north-to-sount) to keep the area of the squares in each row the same...

Comment: Maps are rectangular, not spherical.

Comment: A rectangular represetnation is a distortion, the length of the top and bottom lines may be the same on the map (in inches) but it does not represent the same distance in kilometers on the real--world sphere the map represents

Comment: Allow me to clarify: Since the O.P. is beginning with a map from Google Maps, which is rectangular, the calculations in question will be exact with respect to the map the O.P. is using. This question is more about partitioning a finite rectangular coordinate system than about the specifics of the calculation with respect to a sphere.

Comment: Allow me to correct you. Since the map from google which the OP is using is rectangular, IT is a distorted view.  As soon as the OP mentions the word `Kilometer`, he unambiguously implys he is interested in distances as measured on the real-world object the distorted map represents, (who has a screen that is 1000 kilometers across?) and that is not rectangular, it is a closed curved spherical surface.  Also, the title of the question is "an area of the EARTH is to be partitioned ...."